# Finding cause of "Path not allowed in target domain" error

Tags: macos, high-sierra, logs

This error just started showing up in my log in the last few days. The only software installed, or update recently was the addition of a Wacom tablet. Everything appears to be working properly but I would like to pin down the cause of this new error if possible.

I tried uninstalling the Wacom software but the error persists. Don't know how good the uninstaller is or what settings/permissions etc., are. It possibly didn't revert.

It is also possible that the error is not related to the Wacom and that concerns me more.

How do I dig deeper into what the service is trying to do that is failing?
What path is not allowed, etc?

> Aug 10 08:44:52 MacBook com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.SecurityAgent.195): Path not allowed in target domain: type = uid, path = /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountsDaemon.framework/XPCServices/DataclassOwnersManager.xpc/Contents/MacOS/DataclassOwnersManager error = 1: Operation not permitted, origin = /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/MachServices/SecurityAgent.bundle

Comment: Generally those messages related to security are simple messages that appears for example when you open something that needs your authentication. Eg: Open System Preferences, Select any item which has that lock icon, for example security or network settings. You will notice a message like that on the Log, then if you click the lock to open it, put your password and unlock it, you will see another message on the Log, but now the message will say that the operation was successful. Which means, the "Operation not permitted" was just telling something would need authentication.

Comment: It looks like this error is being logged every time I restart the computer. So it sounds like a startup item is trying to set something it doesn't have permission to change (or is "locked"). I just created a test user account and the message still appears so it is a system level item.